# Active Storage attachments with exact path to local directory and original file name combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filenames, filepath, attachment, rails-activestorage

I want to get the complete path of files stored using active storage.
For example:

'/home/myworkspace/project/storage/folder/original_filname.extension'

Comment: if you mean the origin path of the uploaded file then i think ActiveStorage does not support, in case you mean the path of uploaded file in server (using service: Disk) then the path should be `storage-service-root/2-first-char-of-file-key/next-2-chars/full-of-key`, for example you setup storage service `root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>` then the uploaded file `hello.jpg` is saved with a key  (suppose it's "y7yvtduolswuiy5nx7z9ni29tdyi") in the path `your-app/storage/y7/yv/y7yvtduolswuiy5nx7z9ni29tdyi`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking, this works in Rails 5.2:

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(User.avatar.key)
```